# How to use "i for i in" construction from python in ocaml

Tags: python, ocaml

I have a python function:

```
def foo(n, d = 0):
    if n == 0:return [[]]
    print(x for x in foo(n-1, 0))
    return [[0] + x for x in foo(n-1, 0)] + [[1] + x for x in foo(n-1, 1)]
```

On ocaml it should look like

```
let foo ?(d=0) n =
    if n = 0 then [[]]
    else [[0] @ foo (n-1)] @ [[1] @ foo (n-1) ~d:1]
```

But I have an error:

```
Error: This expression has type int list list
       but an expression was expected of type int list
       Type int list is not compatible with type int
```

I think that I do something wrong with "x for x in foo(n-1, 0)", but I cant understand how to fix it (maybe List.iter may help, but I understand know how)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Python fragment:

[0] + x for x in foo(n-1, 0)

is parsed like this:

([0] + x) for x in foo(n-1, 0)

not like this:

[0] + (x for x in foo(n-1, 0))

In other words, you want to add `0` to the front of each of the generated lists. The way to do this in OCaml is with `List.map`:

```
List.map (fun x -> 0 :: x) (foo (n - 1))
```

OCaml doesn't have list comprehensions, so you shouldn't copy the brackets in Python's `[x for x in ... ]`

Since `foo` wants to call itself recursively, you need to declare it as a recursive function with `let rec`.

If you make these three changes you get this:

```
let rec foo ?(d=0) n =
    if n = 0 then [[]]
    else
        List.map (fun x -> 0 :: x) (foo (n-1)) @
        List.map (fun x -> 1 :: x) (foo (n-1) ~d: 1)
```

A more compact form of this code is something like this:

```
let rec foo n =
  if n = 0 then [[]]
  else let m = foo (n - 1) in List.(map (cons 0) m @ map (cons 1) m)
```

As a side comment, neither of your functions uses the parameter named `d`. This is presumably because they have been trimmed down from more complicated code.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks
Ps is possible to recude code to 90-100 chars? I know that somebody got more shortest code. But probably he use another algorithm

Comment: (I just modified the more compact form to be 106 chars without changing the algorithm. If you remove indentation and other unnecessary spacing you can get it down under 100.)

Comment: Cool, 90 symbols  (without spaces)

Comment: More comon would be pattern matching: `let rec foo = function 0 -> [[]] | n -> let m = foo (n - 1) in List.(map (cons 0) m @ map (cons 1) m)`